# What Is The Liquid Depth Inside The Tank?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, pressure, fluid

[image]

I know that $P_{total}=P_{gauge}+P_{atmosphere}$, so $P_{gauge}=P_{atmosphere}-P_{total}$

$P_{atmosphere}=101.325 KPa$ and $P_{gauge}=0.2 psig=1.38 KPa$.

$P_{gauge}=(0.8 \times sin{30})(900)(9.807) - (900)(9.807)(h)=1.38 KPa$

This implies that $h=0.4m$, however the answer is $0.24m$.

Answer (score 1):

Following your calculations, we equate 1.34 KPa to the height of the liquid then subtract it from 40cm=80cm*sin30.

$$ 1.38/101.325*1000/900=0.01513 \\ 40-15.13= 24.8cm $$